# Laser scan wont update although decay time set to zero- gmapping

Tags: ros, navigation, laser-scan, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having this issue when playing the bag file [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnbfuqilish1lem/test_28jan.bag?dl=0). I recorded this bag file with /scan and /tf on a p3dx which has a UHG-08lx laser sensor. The gmapping works fine. But the laser scans wont update and accumulate into the map, although the decay time is set to zero.
This problem is for every bag file that I record. See attached [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h34dhmcu55er0av/rviz_screenshot_2015_01_28-22_05_30.png?dl=0)

Can someone suggest as to why this is happening and how can I resolve it.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201943/laser-scan-wont-update-although-decay-time-set-to-zero--gmapping/) by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 654 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok i figured out the problem. I was not playing the bag file with the clock running.  I was only playing using $r rosbag play bagfile.bag , when inserting the --clock topic in the end the scans are updating nicely. Thanks for looking into the problem.

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1